# what is the difference between Auth::routes() and Route::auth() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have start working on **laravel 5.4** ,  i have found that there is `Auth::routes()` which is called default in **web route**. I want to more clear with the difference between `Auth::routes()` and  `Route::auth()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Auth::routes()` or `Route::auth()` is equivalent. Infact `Auth::routes()` is defined as:

```
/**
 * Register the typical authentication routes for an application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public static function routes()
{
    static::$app->make('router')->auth();
}
```

where `$app->make('router')` returns an `Illuminate\Routing\Router` instance just like the facade `Route` does.

Answer (score 1):

`Route::auth()` will create the following routes (as found in `Illuminate\Routing\Router.php`:

```
/**
 * Register the typical authentication routes for an application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function auth()
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
}
```

`Auth::routes()` will call the following function (as found in `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth.php`):

```
/**
 * Register the typical authentication routes for an application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public static function routes()
{
    static::$app->make('router')->auth();
}
```

As you can see, the second method creates an instance of the first `Router` class and calls the `auth()` function on it. In the end there is no difference in the two methods. If you have a choice I would personally advice using `Route::auth()` since that seems to be the "default" implementation.